# Unity obter gameobject desativado

Tags: unity3d, game

Meu player tem escudo que fica desativado nele, e tenho um game manager quer cuida para quando o pode ativar o escudo ou não porem quando instancio o player  na cena o game manager não acha o componente do escudo, isso ocorre porque ele esta desativado, se ativo ele acha mais quando acaba o tempo do escudo ele volta à não achar mais alguem sabe o que pode ser ? estou usando:

```
   void Awake()
{
    if (_escudo != null)
    {
        _escudo =  GameObject.Find("Escudo"); //ele acha porque estou iniciando com o escudo ativado 

    }
    else
    {
        InvokeRepeating("checkComponentes", 0f, 2f);
    }
}
```

aqui a função de rotina:

```
 if (_component.input != 0 && _time >= _tempoDuracaoPoderes && _timeDelay <= 0)
    {// recebe o aperto do botao e verifica outras condições antes de ativar 

        StartCoroutine(EscudoForca()); // responsavel por controlar o tempo do escudo
        _buttonescudoForca.enabled = false;
        _time = 0;                    
    }
    else
    {
        _time += Time.deltaTime;
        _timeDelay -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
IEnumerator EscudoForca()
{
    _escudo.SetActive(true); //escudo ativo
    _uiEscudo.SetActive(true);// efeito de lente ativa
    statusBar.fillAmount = 1; 
    anim.SetBool("ativado", true);
    _timeDelay = 5.0f;
   // _escudo = GameObject.Find("Escudo");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_tempoDuracaoPoderes);

   // _escudo = GameObject.Find("Escudo");
    _escudo.SetActive(false);
    _uiEscudo.SetActive(false);
    statusBar.fillAmount = 0;
    anim.SetBool("ativado", false);




}
```

A questão é consigo obter o GameObject desativado para conseguir ativar posteriormente, igual já faço mais isso se o PLAYER estiver na tela se instanciado não funciona.
Desde já agradeço...

Answer (score 1):

A função GameObject.Find somente retorna objetos ativos, para retornar objetos inativos na cena usa a função [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) (Muito cuidado para usar isso, consome bastante processamento)

Se o seu objeto escudo tiver um script fica fácil, caso contrario é melhor criar um gerenciador que tenha a refêrencia desse seu objeto em algum lugar para ter esse acesso;

Outra maneira se acessar o gameobject pai usando [GetComponentsInChildren()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

Existe uma pergunta parecida: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584127/how-to-find-inactive-objects-using-gameobject-find-in-unity3d)